# Why is enzymes "mount" Wrapper just rendering <ul> tags but nothing else?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm learning testing right now and created a very easy example. 
In the component I want to test I render a few `li`elements inside one `ul` tag.

When I wrap the component in a `mount` wrapper and print out the `html` to console I just get `<ul></ul>`

I don't know why? 
The problem now is of course I can't find any `button` elements I want to simulate click on.

Has it something to do how I render the list of todos? Is enzyme not working with renderFunction?

Here is the example: https://codesandbox.io/s/v8ljxo5xn5

The corresponding files are `TodoBody.js` and `TodoBody.test.js`

Thank you!

Comment: todos is an empty array in your test so no li

Comment: Oh My God! Thank you ofc. That little problem took me 2 hours :D

Comment: Your tests seem to test lot of implementation details (expect on wrapper.state, etc). I recommend you to read those articles https://blog.kentcdodds.com/write-tests-not-too-many-mostly-integration-5e8c7fff591c, https://blog.kentcdodds.com/why-i-never-use-shallow-rendering-c08851a68bb7

Comment: Ok thank you appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because todos array is empty so nothing is returned from map (probably [] - you need to check that). Quick solution:

```
describe("the todobody component", () => {
      test("it should call the passed in onDelete func from props", () => {
        const todos = ['test'];
        const test = { onDelete: () => {} };
        jest.spyOn(test, "onDelete");
        const wrapper = mount(<TodoBody onDelete={test.onDelete} todos={todos} />);

        // this just renders <ul></ul> why??

        console.log(wrapper.html());
      });
    });


const renderTodos = () => {
    return todos.map(todo => (
      <li key={`${todo}`}>
        <p>{todo}</p>
        <button onClick={handleDelete} data-test="test-btn-delete">
          X
        </button>
      </li>
    ));
  };
```

console:

```
<ul><li><p>test</p><button data-test="test-btn-delete">X</button></li></ul>
```

Comment: key={`${todo} in li should be something unique like todo.id